# List box reset command getting Run-time error '1004: when run

Tags: excel, vba

I've been getting a Method Range of Object Global failed error on the following code. The code is supposed to reset all the list boxes back to their original value. 
The code works fine if the fields were changed and the user then decided to come back to the sheet to clear the fields before saving it. However, if the user opens the file after saving and decided to clear the fields, the 1004 error is given.

Can anyone tell me how to fix the error? 
Thanks

```
Sub Clear_Staff_Click()

Dim warning
warning = MsgBox("                         !!!! WARNING !!!! " & vbNewLine & "           You are about to ERASE all Staff " & vbNewLine & "                 Are you sure you want to" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "             Erase ALL staff and start over?", vbOKCancel, "!!!!!WARNING !!!!!")
If warning = vbCancel Then Exit Sub



Dim rngLists As Range
Dim ListCell As Range

ActiveSheet.Unprotect "ABCD"
On Error Resume Next
Set rngLists = Sheets("Staff").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rngLists Is Nothing Then
    For Each ListCell In rngLists.Cells
        ListCell.Value = Range(Trim(Mid(Replace(ListCell.Validation.Formula1, ":", String(99, " ")), 2, 99))).Value
    Next ListCell
End If
Range("G7").ClearContents
Range("G10:G15").ClearContents

ActiveSheet.Protect "ABCD"

End Sub
```

The line that flags as an error is:

```
ListCell.Value = Range(Trim(Mid(Replace(ListCell.Validation.Formula1, ":", String(99, " ")), 2, 99))).Value
```

Comment: at what line are you getting this error ?

Comment: This one
    ListCell.Value = Range(Trim(Mid(Replace(ListCell.Validation.Formula1, ":", String(99, " ")), 2, 99))).Value

Comment: what is the value you are trying to assing to `ListCell.Value` ? if you add `Debug.Print Range(Trim(Mid(Replace(ListCell.Validation.Formula1, ":", String(99, " ")), 2, 99))).Value` what are you getting ?

Comment: I ran the Debug.Print and nothing shows up in the immediate window. The value I am trying to assign is called ShiftTypesDay